# Laravel route() - not passing root folder name

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

Thank you in advance,

I have one route defined like

```
Route::get('/registration/verify/{token}', 'UserController@verifyRegisteredEmail')->name('registration.email.verification');
```

I am accessing the route like

```
route('registration.email.verification', ['token' => $email_register_verification_token]);
```

when I am printing above line it is giving them out as below

```
http://localhost/registration/verify/87006dcc95bcf7a9ea83e523f2aa53f9
```

But it should be

```
http://localhost/{root}/registration/verify/87006dcc95bcf7a9ea83e523f2aa53f9
```

Comment: have u try  `APP_URL=http:://.sitename`

Comment: `APP_URL=http:://domain.com` can solve the issue, you have an another question : `Yes this worked, but when i am passing the same things in href of an anchor tag, it is not required to set APP_URL`,  because on your browser your `href` make your current domain as root url. Suppose, your current domain is 2 `domain.com/hello/index.php` and your `href` is `/style.css` then your broswer will call `domain.com/style.css`. If your `href` is `style.css`, then it will call `domain.com/hello/style.css`

Comment: Yupp got your point, thanks a lot @sta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the proper `APP_URL` in `.env`. It only outputs the wrong value from there.

Comment: Yes this worked, but when i am passing the same things in href of an anchor tag, it is not required to set APP_URL

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `APP_URL` inside .env file, and run this command `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

If you have some routes with a same prefix, You can use prefix option in routes groups like this:

```php
Route::prefix('Your Root')->group(function(){
Route::get('/registration/verify/{token}', 'UserController@verifyRegisteredEmail')->name('registration.email.verification');

});
```